# Random walk in R

Tags: r

As per request, pseudocode (I am not a coder, so not good pseudocode here), but,

1. Choose random coordinate in 1x1 square.
2. for (i in 1:iterations)
3. Check to see if coordinates inside 1x1 square.
4. If it is outside the square repeat with previous values of coordinates.
5. Check to see if coordinates fall in the circle inscribed in 1x1 square.
6. If it is, +1 to inside counter.
7. If it isn't, +1 to outside counter.
8. Add value of epsilon in any direction, and repeat.

Finally, `pi_est <- (inside/(inside + outside))*4`

Comment: Adding a pseudocode of your algorithm might make this clearer (and clarify it's not mainly an R question)

Comment: Whether or not a random walk on the square will even give you a suitable estimate depends on whether you construct a walk that has a distribution that gives every point an equal proportion of time over the long run. That in turn will depend on how you handle the boundaries of the square. You should describe how you do that explicitly rather than via the medium of code (where there's the issue of disentangling whether it says what you mean or whether what you meant to do was incorrect). ...ctd

Comment: ctd... Further, you reduce your audience by giving your algorithm in R. *Best to explain it in words*, and as clearly as possible. Once you're sure you have a valid algorithm *then* worry about implementation. Please see our [on-topic help](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) in relation to programming and take care to emphasize the statistical aspect of your question rather than the coding aspects.

Comment: @JuhoKokkala I added pseudocode that may help, I am not experienced at writing pseudocode though.

Comment: What is your question?!?

Comment: @vonjd I had a question but it didn't go the direction I wanted, so I removed it. I can't delete the question though because there's an answer.

Answer (score 2):

As I suggested might be the issue in comments -- with the random walk scheme you're using, I believe you're not going to visit each square equally often... and *that* is going to make your estimate inaccurate (biased).

I suggest you set up a small grid (say 5x5) and run it a long time, then I'd suggest accumulating the results for the six different cell types:

```
C E M E C   (Corner,   Edge,     Midedge, 
E D O D E            Diagonal,  Orthogonal, 
M O X O M                        Xenter)
E D O D E
C E M E C
```

(Since - by symmetry - any differences within those types should be noise-only).

Then (scaling for the fact that the respective counts of each type of cell are 4,8,4,4,4,1) you should be able to see whether they're visited in the right proportions (16%,32% and 4% for 4-, 8- or 1- counts respectively). I believe what you'll find is that the boundary cells are visited more often (relative to their fair proportion) than the middle.

One suggestion would be to "wrap" the edges to that the top and bottom edges and the left and right edges communicate. This avoids the "bounceback" at the edge and instead makes every cell like every other cell; by symmetry you should get equal probability for each cell.